# Open Android app from browser

Tags: java, android, uri

I am trying to open an Android app from a browser. I have read several StackOverflow threads describing a solution to the problem and this is what I have so far:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name="com.webviewtestapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <data android:scheme="Testapp" android:host="launch"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And this is the html `<a href="Testapp://launch"> open testapp </a`

I am using the Firefox browser in Chrome and clicking the link gives a message: **Couldn't find an application to open this link**

How do I fix this ?

Comment: Hi Ashish ,Would you help me,
Have you found above problem solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

to:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
```